# Game Design - Player Data - Am I doing this right?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, game-engine

I use a JDBC/Derby to store highscore data for a puzzle game I am writing. Due to the nature of the game, it will be useful to be able to look at the highscore data based on filters (i.e. show me my highest scores on this level, show me the highest scores on this computer, etc.)

This game also has a "campaign" mode, where the player works toward goals and unlocks achievements.

Currently the campaign data is stored in a Serializable java file that I write out to disk.

However, since the high score data is stored in a database, and because the PlayerID in the highscore table is going to be linked to the campaign file, it feels like I should also be storing the campaign data in the database.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't break the data down at all.  It seems to me that the "Player" table is going to be a hundred+ wide, each column representing the status of a goal or achievement.

I'm not a database guy.  I don't know if this is horrible design or not.  I have read about normal forms 1-5, and I believe that I am in compliance with each form, but I'm suspicious that I'm Doing Something Wrong.

I really want the high scores in a database, and they fit perfectly.  As a side effect, however, I am feeling a strong push to store the campaign booleans / other info in the database as well.  It feels weird to have some data written to files, and other data written to the database, especially when the two things reference each other.

Am I doing something Wrong?  Is it OK to have a table with a hundred or two columns as long as it's actually obeying the normal forms?

Comment: can you give us a snippet that shows how your campaign data is presented in your code? or do you simply want to know, if its bad design or not?

Comment: Maybe a database isn't the right solution here, it sounds a little heavy given the simple use to which you are putting it.

Comment: At one company that shall remain nameless, they stored all the game data in a couple of blobs.  The game object was essentially serialized to a big hunk of data, and that was stored as the blob, later read back out and deserialized back to the game object.  Worked well, and was efficient.  Supported over a million online users.  The blobs are opaque, of course, so you won't be doing reports against them or anything.  That's a trade-off.

Comment: Zhedar: I don't have any useful code to show you. I haven't implemented the campaign-data file yet; I'm trying to address this question before doing so. 

But it's a very straightforward thing: a collection of a hundred or so ints and booleans. Some of the ints will be ScoreIDs from the Scores table.  The exact layout of the code sorta depends on my original question.

Comment: Oliver: That's what I fear, but I don't know what the proper solution is.  The campaign data will be holding ScoreID's, which are database-oriented. 

I don't have enough experience with databases to know what good design is here.  Both options look a little ugly to me: one is to have a table with hundreds of columns, on the other hand I'm storing some data to the flat files and other data in the database with references between them. I was hoping someone with more experience could help shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If most of the columns in the Player table represent the status of a goal or achievement, you could consider that repeating data and model it in child table.

```
Player Table
PlayerId (primary key)
PlayerName

Goals Table
GoalId (primary key)
GoalName

PlayerGoals Table
GoalId (primary key, foreign key to Goal)
PlayerId (primary key, foreign key to Player)
```

The `Goals` table is a master list, which you setup once when you write the game.
When a player achieves something, you insert a row into `PlayerGoals`.

You should model your data based on the expected use cases.  Modelling it in this way (compared to a many-column `Players` table) will make these types of queries easier to write:-

- List players along with how many goals they have completed
- Which goal has been completed by the most players?
- Any other queries which treat Goals generically

It would be easier to add a goal because it becomes a matter of inserting a row into the `Goals` table rather than adding a column.  However, maybe you need to write a bunch of code anyway and this is of no significance.

On the other hand, these types of queries will be easier if you have one big flat Player table with many columns:-

- Get me everything about a particular Player
- List every player that has completed Goal X
- List every player that has completed Goal X and not Goal Y

In the end, you need to choose if you want to make the concept of `Goals` something that you model explicitly in the database or not.  What is right and wrong depends on your priorities.

Comment: This is interesting.  The data is more diffuse than in my example, which "feels" wrong to me.  But I don't have any relevant experience with databases, so I don't understand the benefits/costs to each option.  Could you expand a bit on why this method is desirable?

Comment: In your method, if you add all the achievements to the player table, you'll have 100+ achievements set to 0 until the player actually completes them. All of those 0's are wasted data. If you have an achievements table which links to the player and achievement, you don't even need to record the "uncompleted" achievements.

Comment: In database design, it's almost always better to have more rows than columns, because it results in less complex queries: `select count(*) from PlayerGoals` will give you the total number of goals that have been achieved. How do you do that if there are 100 goal columns?

Comment: Patashu: There can be multiple players, each working on their own campaign.

Comment: @Patashu: Yes, so long as you stop before you get to an Entity-Attribute-Value model.